# Spotting a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

Can anyone spot a complex number $z\in\mathbb C$ such that for $a,b\in \mathbb C$ and $f(w)=\dfrac{w-z}{w-\overline{z}}$, we have $\dfrac{f(a)-f(b)}{1-\overline{f(a)}f(b)}=\dfrac{b-a}{b-\overline{a}}$.  I have been staring at this for some time now...

Comment: Maybe from $f(w^*) = \left(\frac{1}{f(w)}\right)^*$?

Answer (score 3):

According to Maple, your equation simplifies to

$$-{\frac { \left( a-b \right)  \left( -a+\overline{a}-z+\overline{z}
 \right) }{ \left( -b+\overline{a} \right)  \left( -a+\overline{z}
 \right) }}=0
$$

So either $a=b$ or  $\text{Im}\ z = - \text{Im}\ a$.

Comment: +1: Nice. This caters to both interpretations of the question: $a$, $b$ fixed or allowed to vary.

Answer (score 3):

By setting $b=1$, and $a=0$, and doing some algebra we see that $z$ must be real and so $f(w) = 1$.

$$\frac{z}{\overline{z}} - f(1) = 1 - \frac{\overline{z}}{z}f(1) $$

$$z^2 - z\overline{z}f(1) = z\overline{z} - \overline{z}^2 f(1)$$

$$z(z - \overline{z}) = \overline{z}f(1)(z - \overline{z}) $$

If $z \neq \overline{z}$, then $f(1) = \frac{z}{\overline{z}}$

Thus $$\frac{1-z}{1-\overline{z}} = \frac{z}{\overline{z}} = \frac{1 - z + z}{1-\overline{z} + \overline{z}} = 1$$

Thus $z = \overline{z}$